# Parameter name conflict with column name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The following code works fine when put it outside a function and return 1 if it exists at the table.

```
 SET @Result = (SELECT (
     CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `Member` WHERE Username = 'username') THEN 10
     ELSE 1
END) r);

SELECT @Result;
```

But it returns 10 when I am passing the value 'username' to a function like below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FN_CheckUsername`(
   Username VARCHAR(128)
) RETURNS int
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  SET @Result = (SELECT (
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `Member` WHERE Username = Username) THEN 10
     ELSE 1
    END) r);

RETURN @Result;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try naming your username parameter to the `FN_CheckUsername` function something other than `Username`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FN_CheckUsername`(uname VARCHAR(128))
    RETURNS int
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SET @Result = (SELECT (
        CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `Member` WHERE Username = uname)
             THEN 10 ELSE 1 END) r);
    RETURN @Result;
END
```

The parameter and column name could be masking each other, which would result in the exists clause always being true.